# Do we need to restart Azure Function App after updating minimum TLS Version via Portal or Powershell script

Tags: powershell, tls1.2, azure-function-app

Do we need to restart Azure Function App after updating minimum TLS Version via Portal or Powershell script. Or does it internally restart after this change.

Answer (score 0):

This should be performed automatically. After updating you need wait for a few minutes. Have a look of [this](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/04/17/App-Service-and-Functions-hosted-apps-can-now-update-TLS-versions!.html).